# Raising and Lowering Operators of a Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, commutator, linear-algebra

Lets say that I have a Hermitian Hamiltonian $H$ with a non-Hermitian raising operator operator $A$ which satisfies
\begin{equation}
[H,A] = \Omega A, \quad \Omega \in \  \mathbb{R}_{>0}.
\end{equation}

Then it is fairly straightforward to show that $H$ has a symmetry in the form
\begin{equation}
[H, AA^{\dagger}] = 0.
\end{equation}

My question is can I use these statements, and only these statements, to say anything about the relationship between the operators $A$ and $AA^{\dagger}$? Ideally I would like to be able to show that if I have some eigenstate $\vert a \rangle$ where $AA^{\dagger}\vert a \rangle = a \vert a \rangle$ then $(AA^{\dagger})A\vert a \rangle = (a+c_{a})A\vert a \rangle$ with $c_{a}$ some scalar number dependent on the $\vert a \rangle$ at hand, i.e. $A$ acts as a raising/ lowering operator to move between eigenstates of $AA^{\dagger}$.

Obviously there are a number of systems where this is true as these are relationships typically satisfied by ladder operators which appear frequently in Quantum Mechanics. But I am unsure if the first two equations are enough to make statements about the relationship between $A$ and $AA^{\dagger}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you consider a single Fermi oscillator $H=-c^\dagger c$, $\{c,c^\dagger\}=1$ to be a counterexample? Here it is the case that $n c^\dagger |0\rangle = 1 c^\dagger|0\rangle$ but $n c^\dagger |1\rangle = 0 \times c^\dagger |1\rangle$.

Comment: I don't think that this is a counter example as we do have the relationship $[H,c] = \Omega C$ here and the operator $c$ acts as a raising and lowering operator between the eigenstates of $c^{\dagger}c$, it's just that there are only two states on the ladder because we are talking about fermions.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't think you would, but it does strictly speaking violate the way you've defined raising/lowering operators (what is $c$ for it? Is it $+1$ or $-1$?).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. My apologies, I meant that the scalar c can be dependent on the specific $\vert a \rangle $ as opposed to a constant for all  $\vert a \rangle $. I will edit the post.